# Recursive function for creating a binary search tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am currently reading the book *Cracking the code interview*, trying to get a descent level in coding (though I am far from it).

The question is the following: **Given a sorted (increasing order) array with unique integer elements, write an
algorithm to create a binary search tree with minimal height.**

Here is my attempt.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right  = None

class binaryTree:
    def __init__(self,nodes,root):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.root = root

def minimalTree(sortedArray):
    if not sortedArray:
        return None

    else:
        lengthArray = len(sortedArray)
        middle = lengthArray//2
        print("middle = ", middle)
        root = Node(sortedArray[middle])
        leftArray = array.array('i',[])
        rightArray = array.array('i',[])
        if middle == 0:
            return root
        if middle > 0:
            leftArray = sortedArray[0:middle]
            root.left = Node(leftArray[len(leftArray)//2])

        if middle + 1 < lengthArray: 
            rightArray = sortedArray[middle+1:lengthArray]
            root.right = Node(leftArray[len(rightArray)//2])

        return minimalTree(leftArray),minimalTree(rightArray)
```

As you can see, I am not really using the binaryTree class, but I am not sure it is usefull since the tree could be given by its root.

Still I am struggling with recursive algorithms and I don't understand why this one does not return anything.

Note that my question is less about the correctness or efficiency of the algorithm I propose (although comments on this are welcomed as well).

**Edit:** I have edited the code trying to include the base case as suggested.

Comment: Make sure you are prepping for what you think you're prepping for. Depending on the *type* of company this might be a very common interview question... or a very *un*common one.

Comment: For the moment I am less interested in the type of question and more on being able to implement such or such algorithm. Since CTCI is farely basic I believe from the algorthmic point of view, my consern is more on the code itself.

Comment: Fair enough, good attitude.

Comment: Where is the base case? What happens when both of the conditions are False? Put some print functions in to see what is happening.

Comment: @wwii I have tried to include it. Still returns "None" for the child of every root encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Corrections needed in minimalTree function**

Need a base case that returns when array is empty

```
if lengthArray == 0:
  return None
```

You need to recursively assign left and right (independent of middle)

```
# Array split a middle
leftArray = sortedArray[0:middle]
rightArray = sortedArray[middle+1:lengthArray]

# Left side recursion
root.left = minimalTree(leftArray)

# Right side recursion
root.right = minimalTree(rightArray)
```

You need to return root

```
return root
```

**minimalTree Code after above refactoring**

```
def minimalTree(sortedArray):
    lengthArray = len(sortedArray)

    # Base case of recursion
    if lengthArray == 0:
      return None

    # Assign middle
    middle = lengthArray//2
    root = Node(sortedArray[middle])

    # Split Left & Right sides
    leftArray = sortedArray[0:middle]
    rightArray = sortedArray[middle+1:lengthArray]

    # Left & right recursions
    root.left = minimalTree(leftArray)
    root.right = minimalTree(rightArray)

    return root
```

**Display Tree**

```
def display(node): 
    if not node: 
        return

    print (node.value)
    display(node.left)
    display(node.right)
```

**Test**

```
tree = minimalTree([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
display(tree)
```

**Output**

```
3
2
1
5
4
```

Comment: @glmd--not sure if I was clear.  Does it make sense?

Comment: Is there a way to know whether a recursive function should return "itself" (with a recursive argument), or something else? (Hope my question makes sense).

Comment: @GLMD--recursive programs are frequently top/down meaning you express the problem in turns of a sub-problem.  The recursive function returns to answer to the subproblem.  In this case the constructed tree node has three components: 1) value, 2) left, 3) right.  Value was just the value of the middle.  But, we use recursion to obtain the left and right.  The recursion function have to return their node value so we can make the assignment of left &  right.